# How to add "create on" comment in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to add "create on" comment in eclipse every time in create a new class file? I know the alt+shift+j option creates comments for adding name to the eclipse class file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Code Style* -> *Code Templates*

Expand *Comments* -> *Types*

Edit the template for comments created for new types. Use the `${date}` token.